# encoding of response http response body

Tags: java, http, https, okhttp

I'm using `okhttp` library for sending request to rest api. this is my java code for sending request to `https`:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, requestBody);

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://examplesite.com/json/").post(body)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01")
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip").addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String res = new String(response.body().string().getBytes("UTF-8"));

    System.out.println(res);
```

the `res` variable is: `�CU8{$���'L�@R�W*�$��b�H�E�l�K�C�   30��}c&,p��q���)+3�R�28���#SC�`

what is the encoding of above text?

this is response header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:95
Content-Type:application/json
```

I can't understand what is the encoding of the response body. whatever when I send request by postman extension on chrome that response body is a normal json.
attend that the protocol is `https` and I think `okhttp` library handle encrypting and decripting data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove this:

```
 .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
```

When you do this, you’re telling OkHttp that you want to manage your own response compression.

If you don’t explicitly configure the `Accept-Encoding`, OkHttp will take care of you. It’ll add the header to the request, and decompress the response.

Comment:  Rocket science! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
String commentUri = "http://comment.bilibili.com/4.xml";

    Log.d("request_comment url", commentUri);
    Request requestComment = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
//                .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
            .url(commentUri)
            .build();
```

I meet the same problem, I used okhttp 3.2.0 like this,but still cannot unpack defalte, it returns like this :  U��n�0E���k{���4v|]W�vۑ⸊��8

delete add header accept-encoding didn't help